# Alternatives to Google webapps?

Tags: webapp-rec

I find myself using Google products most of the time. These are Google Search, GMail, Reader, Picasa, Groups, Documents, Maps, Translate and so on... They are not bad generally, but I think I might be missing something better just because Google's offer is more popular. Are there some free and better alternatives to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is sort of a loaded question because it really depends on your needs and how you plan to use the various tools.  Do you want web only apps?  Do you plan to work in a sometimes disconnected state?  Will traditional desktop apps that include some collaboration features work for you?

That being said, here's a rough list of comparable apps:

- Google search: Bing
- Gmail: Yahoo Mail!, Windows Live Mail, Thunderbird as a client
- Reader: Firefox plugin called Sage, Thunderbird's built in reader
- Picasa: Windows Live Photo Gallery, Flickr or Facebook (For storing images and slight editing)
- Groups: Yahoo groups, Windows Live Groups
- Documents: OpenOffice, Office Live
- Maps: Bing maps, MapQuest
- Translate: Babelfish, FreeTranslation.com

Here's an article I found on this subject: http://www.lifehack.org/articles/technology/getting-free-of-googles-grip-the-10-top-alternatives.html

Answer (score 4):

there's so many alternatives... you can check out the ZOHO suite: http://www.zoho.com/
it's pretty big.

Answer (score 4):

The big new one is Microsoft **Office Web Apps**, which you can reach here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/

You can read a **comparison between Office Web Apps and the Google App suite** [on this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5560352/how-does-office-web-apps-compare-to-google-docsr).

Is there anything specifically that you don't like about the Google Apps? **What would you be looking for in new apps?** The only ones from your list I would suggest alternatives to are Flickr for Picasa, however I am sure you already know of that, and **using any browser extension (what browser do you use?) for translation  instead of going to Google's translate page** to prevent having to open a separate web page and copy and paste into it.

In my opinion though, **you would be better off sticking with the Google's offerings**, I generally find that they are superior to most others.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft offers [Office Live Workspace](http://workspace.officelive.com/). I haven't tried it myself, but in some comparisons I've read that Google Docs has better collaborative editing whereas Office Live Workspace has some unique features.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Google Reader, I'd encourage you to check out [Feedly](http://feedly.com/). It uses Google Reader to store your feeds, so there's no migration required to try it out, but it offers a much better experience, in my opinion, to the standard Google Reader interface.

Answer (score 1):

[AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/) lists alternatives to popular and obscure PC, Mac, Linux, and web apps.

For instance, here's the page with alternatives for [Google Groups](http://alternativeto.net/software/google-groups/).

All of the Google products I checked had listings there.